# Can OptaPlanner use Superclass constraints?

Tags: superclass, optaplanner

Is it possible to calculate the score with constraints defined on a superclass of a planning entity or fact? Do I need to do something special for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we support it. Do note that both the superclass and the subclass most both be registered in the solver config and have a @PlanningEntity annotation.

See the examination example - that has FollowingExam extends Exam.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look it up